# Autofill Formula down the column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to autofill formulas of **column B** such that it goes down as **B16, c16, d16, e16, and so on!**

```
| A |                 B                  |
|---|------------------------------------|
| 1 | =IFERROR('Data Over Time'!B$16,"") |
| 2 | =IFERROR('Data Over Time'!C$16,"") |
| 3 | =IFERROR('Data Over Time'!D$16,"") |
```

Can that be down with autofill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but i think you try to transpose range 'Data Over Time'!b16:e16 (or longer)

If you want to have this in vertical form and free from error messages, you can write:

```
=iferror(transpose('Data Over Time'!b16:e16))
```